# Инструменты для создания CSS - JS анимации

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

**UPD:** Соберу сюда ссылки из ответов и другие найденные:

• https://loading.io/

• https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

• http://animista.net/play/basic/scale-up

[везде куча примеров анимаций единичных элементов]. Всё еще не найден ресурс с возможностью сразу комбинировать в одном месте анимацию из множества элементов и на месте сгенерировать сложный код движения всех составляющих*)

---

Как работают профессиональные CSS-аниматоры? Немного поигрался с анимациями... и не то, что там есть что-то прям сложное, но с первого взгляда это выглядит как нудное задротство - сидеть и прикидывать-вымерять пиксели.

Вопрос: какие удобные инструменты есть для упрощения создания анимаций?

Воображение нарисовало инструмент, где можно было бы одновременно создать кучу разных элементов, дать им классы, назначить положения элементов в нескольких состоянииях от 0% до 100%, в формате 'drag-and-drop' - и получить готовый код... Но гугл не нашел такой ‍♀️

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Есть универсальный инструмент, который почти полностью отвечает вашим запросам,**

С помощью мышки можно выбрать размер, цвет, скорость анимации для различных объектов : иконок, лоадеров, прогрессбаров, текста и т.д

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Анимацию на выходе можно получить в трёх видах CSS, SVG, GIF

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Ресурс требует регистрации, но она проста и даже не требует
  подтверждения ответным письмом. Даётся возможность скачать, но только
  один раз. Правда с другого браузера можно скачать ещё раз.

Есть примеры лоадеров, которые можно забрать просто так.

**Ниже некоторые образцы:**

*Пульсирующее сердце*

```css
.lds-heart {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 32px 32px;
}
.lds-heart div {
  top: 23px;
  left: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: crimson;
  animation: lds-heart 1.2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.lds-heart div:after,
.lds-heart div:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: crimson;
}
.lds-heart div:before {
  left: -17px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
.lds-heart div:after {
  top: -17px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
@keyframes lds-heart {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  39% {
    transform: scale(0.85);
  }
  45% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-heart"><div></div></div>
```

***Ripple***

```css
.lds-ripple {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid dodgerblue;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
}
.lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
@keyframes lds-ripple {
  0% {
    top: 28px;
    left: 28px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-ripple"><div></div><div></div></div>
```

***spin-dash***

```css
.lds-roller {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-roller div {
  animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  transform-origin: 32px 32px;
}
.lds-roller div:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -3px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.036s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.072s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
  top: 54px;
  left: 45px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.108s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
  top: 57px;
  left: 39px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -0.144s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
  top: 58px;
  left: 32px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -0.18s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
  top: 57px;
  left: 25px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -0.216s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
  top: 54px;
  left: 19px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: -0.252s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
  top: 50px;
  left: 14px;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: -0.288s;
}
.lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
  top: 45px;
  left: 10px;
}
@keyframes lds-roller {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

***Spinner***

```css
.lds-spinner {
  color: official;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.lds-spinner div {
  transform-origin: 32px 32px;
  animation: lds-spinner 1.2s linear infinite;
}
.lds-spinner div:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 29px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #000;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
.lds-spinner div:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
@keyframes lds-spinner {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

### SVG иконка

```html
<svg class="lds-blocks" width="200px"  height="200px"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
<rect x="19" y="19" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="40" y="19" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.125s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="61" y="19" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.25s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="19" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.875s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="61" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.375s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="19" y="61" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.75s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="40" y="61" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.625s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
<rect x="61" y="61" width="20" height="20" fill="#e4e408">
  <animate attributeName="fill" values="#d16c18;#e4e408;#e4e408" keyTimes="0;0.125;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.5s" calcMode="discrete"></animate>
</rect>
</svg>
```

Источник: https://loading.io/css/

Ресурс платный, но автор даёт возможность скачать бесплатно библиотеку CSS

https://loading.io/css/loading.css

с подробными объяснениями, как самому довольно просто сделать всё это

https://loading.io/animation/

**CSS анимации работают во всех браузерах включая `IE11` и `Edge`**

### Update

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[Vivus-instant](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/)**

Всё очень просто: перетаскиваете иконку в окно проги. Делаете или оставляете по умолчанию параметры анимации, там их самый минимум.
***Анимация будет основана на изменении `stroke-dashoffset` от максимума до нуля.***
Соответствующие стили, классы и @keyfframes прописываются автоматически.

*Утилита очень удобна, если нужно быстро сделать анимацию рисования линий.*

Comment: да, это крутой ресурс

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сбой системы наверное, я обращался к другому.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  Плюсики сразу были поставлены) Не хотел спешить с галочкой, на случай "если вдруг". За ответ спасибо) А того, что я искал видимо еще в мире не существует. Но такое принципиально не невозможно создать (вероятно, через Fabric JS)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а что Вы искали, просто интересно ?)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q , https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/xvh58sLj/ - игрался, оттуда и появился вопрос) Если делать не просто единичную анимированную кнопку, а какого-нибудь персонажа или условного танцующего пингвина с множеством деталей... то руки-ноги-тело-голова независимо друг от друга должны двигаться по точным траекториям, чтобы это выглядело органично. Можно было бы на JS поколдовать, создать редактор... где как-минимум, перетаскивая элементы куда надо, при клике на кнопку можно было записать все текущие координаты.

Answer (score 4):

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Хороший CSS аниматор, также можете использовать JQuery анимации по типу `.fadeOut()` и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Есть замечательное приложение [Keyshape](https://www.keyshapeapp.com/), стоит всего $30, но оно только для Mac.

Еще есть [SVGator](https://www.svgator.com/), это онлайн-приложение с ежемесячной оплатой, есть триал-период.